# How do you prove that $tr(B^{T} A )$ is a inner product?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products, trace

> Consider the vectorspace of all real $m \times n$ vectors and define an 
>   inner product $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(B^T   A)$.    "tr" stands for "trace" 
>       which is the sum of the diagonal entries of a matrix.

How do you prove that $\operatorname{tr}(B^T   A)$ is indeed a inner product?

Kind regards

Comment: Well, which properties are needed? Which do you have trouble with?

Comment: For intuition, note that $tr(B^T A)$ is what you'd get if you reshaped $A$ and $B$ into column vectors and took the standard inner product.

Comment: It is an inner product on $M_n(R)$ I believe, but not $M_n(C)$.

Comment: For $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ you'd need the conjugate transpose of $B$ as oppose to the transpose. So $tr(B^* A)$ should be an inner product.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For every $A=(A_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ we have
$$
\langle A,A\rangle=\text{tr}(A^TA)=\sum_{i=1}^n(A^TA)_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mA^T_{ij}A_{ji}=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2 \ge 0,
$$
and
$$
\langle A,A\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}^2 = 0\iff (A_{ij}=0 \quad \forall i,j) \iff A=0
$$
Since
$$
\text{tr}(X^T)=\text{tr}(X), \quad \text{tr}(X+Y)=\text{tr}(X)+\text{tr}(Y), \quad \text{tr}(\lambda X)=\lambda\text{tr}(X)
$$
for every $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore, for every $A,B, C \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle A,B\rangle&=&\text{tr}(B^TA)=\text{tr}((B^TA)^T)=\text{tr}(A^TB)=\langle B,A\rangle,\\
\langle \lambda A+B,C\rangle&=&\text{tr}(C^T(\lambda A+B))=\text{tr}(\lambda C^TA+C^TB)=\lambda\text{tr}(C^TA)+\text{tr}(C^TB)\\
&=&\lambda\langle A,C\rangle+\langle B,C\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: what does this imply about the relationship between $\text{tr}(A^TB) \text{and } \text{tr}(AB^T)$?

Answer (score 13):

If $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$ and $C=B^TA=(c_{ij})$ then
$$(c)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^m b_{ki}a_{kj}$$

$$\mathrm{tr}(B^TA)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m b_{ki}a_{ki}$$
so we see that $\langle.,.\rangle$ is an inner product (Euclidian) by identifying $\mathcal M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$.

Comment: Nice answer, although you should probably make the minor ajustments necessary to handle the "non-square matrix" case (which is the OP's original setting).

Comment: Done. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sistemas.fciencias.unam.mx/~erhc/algebra_lineal_20181/traza_ortogonalidad.pdf) can help, do the proof is in Spanish and proved for the complex case.

Answer (score 6):

You want to verify all the properties of a real inner product (since we're looking at a real vector space). Using your notation $\langle A,B \rangle = \mathrm{tr}(B^T A)$, we want to check that:

1. $\langle A,B \rangle = \langle B,A \rangle $ (symmetry)
2. $\langle cA + B, C \rangle = c \langle A,C \rangle + \langle B,C \rangle$ (linearity)
3. $\langle A, A \rangle > 0$ unless $A = 0$ (definiteness)

You'll need to use some properties about the trace in order to prove some of these conditions hold.

Answer (score 2):

As it is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product), we can use the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) on matrices $\boldsymbol A$ and $\boldsymbol B$ to rewrite the trace of the product as

$$\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left(\boldsymbol A^T \boldsymbol B \right) &= \text{vec}\left(\boldsymbol B\right)^T \text{vec}\left(\boldsymbol A\right) \\
&= \left\langle\text{vec}\left(\boldsymbol A\right),\text{vec}\left(\boldsymbol B\right)\right\rangle
\end{align}$$

which is the inner product for the vector case.