# How to prove $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

there is a similar thread here [Coordinate-free proof of $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(BA)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311580/coordinate-free-proof-of-operatornametrab-operatornametrba), but I'm only looking for a simple linear algebra proof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ an $n\times m$ matrix we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{tr}(AB)
&=&\sum_{i=1}^m(AB)_{ii}\cr
&=&\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{ki}\cr
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^mB_{ki}A_{ik}\cr
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n(BA)_{kk}\cr
&=&\operatorname{tr}(BA).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: most general proof

Comment: Very Noice!! : )

Comment: Very, very elegant :)

Answer (score 48):

Observe that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, $A=(a_{ij})$, and $B=(b_{ij})$, then
$$(AB)_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{ki},$$
so
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk}b_{kj}.
$$
Conclude calculating the term $(BA)_{ii}$ and comparing both traces.

Comment: Perhaps another useful observation is that if we transpose the matrix A, we get basically the standard inner product. See, for example, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476802/how-do-you-prove-that-trbt-a-is-a-inner-product/476813#476813).

Answer (score 14):

> For any couple $(A,B)$ of $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries, the following identity holds:
>   $$ \operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA).$$

**Proof**. Assuming $A$ is an invertible matrix, $AB$ and $BA$ share the same characteristic polynomial, since they are conjugated matrices 
due to $BA = A^{-1}(AB)A$. In particular they have the same trace. Equivalently, they share the same eigenvalues (counted according to their
algebraic multiplicity) hence they share the sum of such eigenvalues. On the other hand, if $A$ is a singular matrix then 
$A_\varepsilon\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} A+\varepsilon I$ is an invertible matrix for any $\varepsilon\neq 0$ small enough. It follows that 
$\operatorname{Tr}(A_\varepsilon B) = \operatorname{Tr}(B A_\varepsilon)$, and since $\operatorname{Tr}$ is a continuous operator, 
by considering the limits of both sides as $\varepsilon\to 0$ we get $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(BA)$ just as well.

Comment: What if $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n\times m$ matrix then is the statement $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ true

Comment: How is $A+\epsilon I$ invertible for $\epsilon$ small enough? I know that the invertible matrix is a dense set in the set of the matrices, but this statement is stronger that that.

Comment: @R.W.Prado: since the identity matrix commutes with any matrix, the spectrum of $A+\varepsilon I$ is the spectrum of $A$ translated by $\epsilon$, and a matrix is invertible iff $0$ does not belong to its spectrum.

Comment: Nice argument! I first thought using Schur's decomposition.

Answer (score 12):

The efficient @hjhjhj57: answer

$$\text{Tr}(AB) = \text{Tr}(BA)= \sum a_{ij}  b_{ji}$$

Now we can start to understand why if we do a circular permutation of the factors the expression

$$\text{Tr}( A_1 A_2 \ldots A_m)$$

does not change, and what is the expression.

Assume now $A$,$B$ square. Then certainly $\det(AB) = \det(BA)$, using the multiplicative property of the $\det$.

In fact, the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial, so in particular the same trace, and the same determinant.

Comment: amazing... they have the same characteristic polynomial? how to show that ?

Comment: @athos: $\det(A) \det( t - BA) =\det(t A - ABA) = \det(t- AB) \det A$. This holds for all same size square matrices $A$,$B$. Look at it as an identity in the entries of $A$,$B$ and also $t$. An equality of two polynomials. Now divide by the non-zero polynomial $\det A$...

Comment: Trace of a matrix is sum of its eigenvalues. Note that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: @JankoBracic: They do have the same eigenvalues, including zeroes, for linear operators on a finite dimensional vector space. However, you probably consider the case of  $A$,$B$ elements in an algebra and looking at spectra then your statement is the right one in this  general case.

Comment: Once the case for two matrices has been proved, the cyclic property can easily be proved by induction.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 how are u sure that $det(A)$ is non-zero?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 do you believe that this answer is correct?

Comment: @istillhavehope I do, what makes you think otherwise? Note that all they say is independent of the value of the determinants.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 but if determinant is zero , they can't divide the expression by determinant ... that's my problem