# Some doubts and questions with the trace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\text{tr}A$ be the trace of the matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

- I realize that $\text{tr}A: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is obviously linear (but how can I write down a *formal* proof?). However, I am confused about how I should calculate $\text{dim}(\text{Im(tr)})$ and $\text{dim}(\text{Ker(tr)})$ and a basis for each of these subspace according to the value of $n$.
- Also, I don’t know how to prove that $\text{tr}(AB)= \text{tr}(BA)$, and I was wondering if it is true that $\text{tr}(AB)= \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(B)$.
- Finally, I wish to prove that $g(A,B)=\text{tr}(AB)$ is a positive defined scalar product if $A,B$ are *symmetric*; and also $g(A,B)=-\text{tr}(AB)$ is a scalar product if $A,B$ are *antisymmetric*. Can you show me how one can proceed to do this?

I would really appreciate some guidance and help in clarifying the doubts and questions above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the trace of $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Do you see why $tr(AB) \neq tr(A)tr(B)$?

Proof of $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ can be found here: [How to prove tr AB = tr BA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099745/how-to-prove-tr-ab-tr-ba).

To prove the trace is linear we have to check that $Tr(c(A + B)) = cTr(A) + cTr(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The image is very easy.  All you really need is the fact that there is some $A$ with $\text{tr}\; A \ne 0$.  As for the kernel: note that given all but one entry of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ (if that one is ...), you can choose a value for that one to make the trace $0$.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit (and  address the other points too)?