# What are the values of $a$ and $b$ given these 2 matrix conditions?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I recently took an algebra test, and one of the questions was like this *(apologise upfront because I don't remember the exact matrix elements, but the idea is essentially the same):*

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices. We know that:
>   $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3&4\end{bmatrix}, \quad
>  BA=\begin{bmatrix}3 & a \\b &2\end{bmatrix}$$ What can be said about
>   values $a$ and $b$? What *possible* values *can* they have?

The real exam problem gave me only 4 options and only 1 was correct (it was a multiple-choice test question). The first 3 of the answers suggested possible values for $a$ and $b$, whereas the last answer stated $\text{(d)Nothing can be said about a and b}$.

How would you proceed? I spent like 10 minutes trying several things to no avail. **No further conditions were given on A nor B. We only know they are square and 2x2.**

---

### What I tried:

I stablished: $$AB=X, \quad BA=Y$$ Then I multiplied by the inverse of $B$ (assuming it has an inverse), to reach: $$A=XB^{-1}=B^{-1}Y$$ $$B=A^{-1}X=YA^{-1}$$
But I really don't know where this will lead me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing can be said besides the fact that $a\neq0$ and that $b=\frac 8a$ (which means that both matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3&a\\b&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ have the same determinant). Indeed, if you take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac a4\\1&\frac a8\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{pmatrix}\frac52&3\\\frac4a&\frac8a\end{pmatrix},$$then$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }BA=\begin{pmatrix}3&a\\\frac8a&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I don't remember the exact matrix elements but I'm sure they met $\text{tr}(AB)=\text{tr}(BA)$. I modified the question. What can be said now?

Comment: PD: Can you please point me to an article where they demonstrate that $\text{tr}(AB)=\text{tr}(BA)$ always need to be true?

Comment: It is *not* true. What I wrote was that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, it was a Latex typo.

Comment: There's an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099745/how-to-prove-tr-ab-tr-ba).

Comment: Thank you Jose. Now what do you think about my question?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think?

Comment: Wow... the condition I was missing is that $det(AB)=det(BA)$. Then out of the 4 values for $a$ and $b$ that I was given, I just needed to find the one that met $b=/8/a$. So dumb of me, thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, in matrix $BA$ you wrote $1/a$ instead of $8/a$.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on the same lines, typed it too slowly...

First of all we have the two conditions
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(AB) &=\det(BA)\ ,\\
\operatorname{tr}(AB) &=\operatorname{tr}(BA)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
the trace condition is fulfilled, the determinant condition becomes
$$ab=8\ .$$
We consider only such values of $a,b$, show that each matrix can be realized (in many ways). For this, we search for a general $B$ in the form
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Then the condition $AB=BA$ can be equivalently rewritten $ (AB)^{-1}=(BA)^{-1}$, so we get both
$$
\begin{aligned}
A^{-1} &= B(B^{-1}A^{-1})=\frac 1{-2}
\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}4&-2\\-3&1\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\\
A^{-1} &= (A^{-1}B^{-1})B=\frac 1{-2}
\begin{bmatrix}2&-a\\-b&3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&t\end{bmatrix}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This leads to an algebraic system in $x,y,z,t$ with parameters $a,b$,
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
4x-3y &= 2x-az\\
-2x+y &= 2y-at\\
4z-3t &= -bx+3z\\
-2z+t &= -by+3t\\
ab &= 8
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
and the solution is simplest (found and) typed using a computer algebra system, here [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: var( 'x,y,z,t,b' );
sage: a = 8/b
sage: AB = matrix( 2, 2, [1,2,3,4] ) 
sage: BA = matrix( 2, 2, [3,a,b,2] )
sage: B  = matrix( 2, 2, [x,y,z,t] )
sage: Ainverse1 = B * AB.inverse() 
sage: Ainverse2 = BA.inverse() * B
sage: solve( [ Ainverse1[j,k] == Ainverse2[j,k] for j in [0,1] for k in [0,1] ], [x,y,z,t] ) 
[[x == r4, y == r3, z == 1/8*b*(3*r3 - 2*r4), t == 1/8*b*(r3 + 2*r4)]]
```

so any choice of `r3`, `r4` above leads to a solution. My choice is $y=r_3=0$, $x=r_4=4$, so 
$$
B =
\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\-b&b\end{bmatrix}
\ ,
\qquad
A =
\begin{bmatrix}3/4&2/b\\7/4&4/b\end{bmatrix}
\ .
$$
Code and check:

```
sage: B = matrix( 2, 2, [4,0,-b,b] )
sage: B
[ 4  0]
[-b  b]
sage: A = AB * B.inverse()
sage: A
[3/4 2/b]
[7/4 4/b]
sage: A*B
[1 2]
[3 4]
sage: B*A
[  3 8/b]
[  b   2]
```

Comment: Good answer, thank you ;)