# If $AB-BA = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & x& 0\\ 0&0& -1 \end{pmatrix}$, find $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine all real numbers $x$ for which there exists $3 \times 3$ real matrices $A$ and $B$ such that

$$AB-BA = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & x& 0\\
0&0& -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Take the trace of both sides.

Comment: Should it be equal? I mean, is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099745/how-to-prove-operatornametrab-operatornametrba), we have
$$\begin{align}\text{tr}(AB - BA) &= \text{tr}(AB) - \text{tr}(BA)\\ &= \text{tr}(AB) - \text{tr}(AB) \\&= 0 \end{align}$$
But
$$\text{tr}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & x& 0\\
0&0& -1
\end{pmatrix} = 1+x-1 = x $$
Hence, $x = 0$

Comment: You just show that for such matrices to exist $x$ must be zero. The proof will be complete if you show that for $x=0$ you can in fact find $A,B$ in those conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Since $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$, you see that $tr(AB-BA) = 0$. So, the trace of the rhs must also be zero, i.e. $x = 0$.

We have proven so far that, if the equality holds, we must have $x=0$. To complete the proof we must check that when $x=0$, it is possible to find such matrices. We can take for instance
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad B = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: It is not if and only if!

Comment: @TheMathematician I did not say it was if and only if. I am just guarantying that there exists at least one $x$ is those conditions. The first part of the proof just says that the only $x$ that could fit is $x=0$, but does not establish that it actually does.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your comment