# Whether ${\rm trace}(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^TM)={\rm trace}(\mathbf{x}^TM\mathbf{x})$

Tags: matrices, trace

If $\mathbf{x} \in R^n,M \in R^{n \times n}$,and trace(.) is the sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix,whether the above conclusion is hold,if so,how to prove,thanks in advance

Comment: $x^T M x$ is a scalar, and $xx^T M$ is a matrix

Comment: @thewatcher doesn't matter. the trace is scalar

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and type your question inside the body on your post, not only (and not even necessarily) in the title.

Comment: Multiduplicate: [How to prove $\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099745). Simply apply this to the two matrices $A=x\in\Bbb R^{n\times1}$ and $B=x^TM\in\Bbb R^{1\times n}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. More generally, the trace is invariant to cyclic permutations:

$$Tr(ABC)=Tr(BCA)=Tr(CAB).$$

You can prove this using the regular trace identity

$$Tr(XY)=Tr(YX),$$

and let $X=AB,Y=C$ or let $X=A,Y=BC.$

Comment: Is that true for vectors?$\mathbf{x}$ is a vector here

Comment: @TiantianHe Of course, a vector is just an $n\times 1$ matrix. The identity is true so long as the matrices are conformable (i.e. their products are well defined)